# PHP, Mysql - Show a fixed number of results from database based on multiple ids

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here are the sample tables:

```
Table - user
uid | name
1       X
2       Y
3       Z
4       W

Table - dessert
id | name | price
1       A    5.00
2       B    10.00
3       C    11.00
4       D    23.00
5       E    3.00
6       F    7.00

Table - fav_dessert
uid | dessert_id
1       2
1       3
2       3
2       4
3       5
4       6


Table - related_dessert
dessert_id          | rel_id
(Fkey->dessert->id) | (Fkey->dessert->id)
  1                    5
  2                    3
  2                    4
  2                    5
  5                    6
```

How to find out the user who has similar taste in dessert. Suppose  user `X` searches for the users who have similar taste to his. In the search results I want to show the users who has same favorite desserts as `X` then show the users who likes the related desserts of user `X`'s favorite dessert.
The output should be :

```
Y
Z
```

How can i get what I want? BTW, I need the first `N` number of rows. Thanks.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: but `Z` doesn't have similar taste with `X`

Comment: @HastaDhana, X loves dessert 2 and 3, 3 is loved by Y as well, therefore Y is in the example.  

Dessert 2 is similar to dessert 3, 4 and 5 and since Z loves 5, user Z is shown as well

Answer (score 0):

you could try using an inner join on the suquery for the dessert_id with count of distinc user > 1

```
select f.uid, u.name
from fav_dessert f 
inner join user u on f.uid=u.uid
inner join (
select dessert_id
from fav_dessert 
group by dessert_id 
having count(distinct uid)>1
) t on t.dessert_id = f.dessert_id
```